# changing value type

Tags: jquery

```
$.fn.findMaxHeight = function() {
    var wrapperHeight = $(this).height();
    var wrapperMaxHeight = $(this).css('max-height');

    if ( wrapperHeight == wrapperMaxHeight ) {
        alert("max-height reached");
    } else {
        alert("not yet");
    }
}
$('.subscription-wrapper').findMaxHeight();
$('.payment-wrapper').findMaxHeight();
```

... doesn't work because `.css()` returns `300px` and `.height()` returns `300` so they can't be compared. how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `parseInt`.

Specifically,

```
var wrapperMaxHeight = parseInt($(this).css('max-height'), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your CSS height using `parseInt`

```
var wrapperMaxHeight = parseInt($(this).css('max-height'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parseFloat instead of parseInt. The height is not always an integer! Half-pixels are possible.